# Plot colored grid

Tags: plotting, color, warning-messages, options

Goal: plot 3D lattice with knots of different color.

Input:

```
xyzF={{1, 1, 1, color111}, {1, 1, 2, color112},...,{N,N,N,colorNNN}}
```

Working example to color the grid into Hue[x]:

```
xyzF = Flatten[Table[{i, j, k, i*j*k/27.}, {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}, {k, 1, 3}], 2]
xyz = Map[#[[1 ;; 3]] &, xyzF]
ListPointPlot3D[xyz, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[x]]]
```

NOT working example to color the grid into F[x,y,z]:

```
returnF[x_, y_, z_] := Module[{res},

Map[If[#[[1]] == x && #[[2]] == y && #[[3]] == z, res = #[[4]]] &, xyzF];
Return[Hue[res]]

];
ListPointPlot3D[xyz, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, returnF[x,y,z]]]
```

Error message:

```
Ignoring invalid graphics directive Hue[$CellContext`$784].
```

What is the problem and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Source of the problem

Your code works as written with a single change: the addition of `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`.  (You do not need a separate `Function` as `returnF` can be used independently.)

```
ListPointPlot3D[xyz, ColorFunction -> returnF, ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

[`ColorFunctionScaling`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunctionScaling.html) defaults to `True`, therefore all coordinates are scaled to fall within the range [0,1] and these values do not match anything in `xyzF`.

#### Recommended method

However you can simplify things significantly by using [`Graphics3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html) directly.  (I shall use a larger [`PointSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PointSize.html) so that you can see the coloration more easily.)

```
Graphics3D[{
  PointSize[0.02],
  {Hue[#4], Point[{#, #2, #3}]} & @@@ xyzF
 }
 , Axes -> True
]
```

[image]

Or a bit more efficiently (i.e. faster rendering) with a single [`Point`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Point.html) expression and [`VertexColors`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexColors.html):

```
Graphics3D[{
  PointSize[0.02],
  Point[xyz, VertexColors -> (Hue /@ xyzF[[All, 4]])]
 }, 
 Axes -> True
]
```

See [`BoxRatios`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoxRatios.html) if you want the graphic to have a different shape, e.g. `ListPointPlot3D` defaults to `BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.4}`.

Comment: Thank you, Mr.Wizard! It does the trick, but I'm a bit confused about the error message. Do you understand what's going on there?

Comment: @user1541776 Sorry, I forgot to address that, and it is simple and important.  I shall update my answer.